# Почему при клике на лейбл событие отрабатывает 2 раза?

Tags: javascript

Почему при клике на лейбл событие отрабатывает 2 раза при том, что слушатель висит вообще на ul

```js
const radioReq = document.querySelectorAll('.radio-req');

radioReq.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
  })
});
```

```html
<form class="tw-space-y-5 form-promotion">
  <div class="req form-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Полное наименование компании" data-enter="fullname">
  </div>
  <div class="req inn form-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="ИНН компании" data-enter="inn">
  </div>
  <p>Категория товаров:</p>
  <ul class="radio-req tw-gap-x-2 tw-max-w-[400px] lg:tw-max-w-[770px] tw-grid-cols-2 tw-grid radio-req-active !tw-space-y-2.5  lg:!tw-space-y-5 !tw-mt-0" data-radio="category" data-enter="category">
    <li class="tw-flex !tw-mt-5 tw-cursor-pointer">
      <input type="radio" id="clothing" class="tw-cursor-pointer" name="category" value="Одежда">
      <label for="clothing" class="tw-cursor-pointer">Одежда</label>
    </li>
    <li class="tw-flex !tw-m-0 tw-cursor-pointer">
      <input type="radio" id="accessories" name="category" value="Аксессуары" class="tw-cursor-pointer">
      <label for="accessories" class="tw-cursor-pointer !tw-mb-0">Аксессуары</label>
    </li>
    <li class="tw-flex tw-cursor-pointer">
      <input type="radio" id="products" name="category" value="Продукты питания" class="tw-cursor-pointer">
      <label for="products" class="tw-cursor-pointer">Продукты питания</label>
    </li>
    <li class="tw-flex tw-cursor-pointer">
      <input type="radio" id="cosmetics" name="category" value="Косметика" class="tw-cursor-pointer">
      <label for="cosmetics" class="tw-cursor-pointer">Косметика</label>
    </li>
    <li class="tw-flex tw-cursor-pointer">
      <input type="radio" id="home" name="category" value="Товары для дома" class="tw-cursor-pointer">
      <label for="home" class="tw-cursor-pointer">Товары для дома</label>
    </li>
    <li class="tw-flex tw-cursor-pointer">
      <input type="radio" id="children" name="category" value="Товары для детей" class="tw-cursor-pointer">
      <label for="children" class="tw-cursor-pointer">Товары для детей</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button id="next-form" class="next-form">подать заявку</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Но щелчок по метке также автоматически отправляет событие щелчка соответствующему элементу ввода, поэтому это рассматривается как щелчок по флажку. Затем всплытие событий приводит к тому, что это событие щелчка запускается для содержащего элемента, который является меткой, поэтому ваш обработчик запускается снова.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501497/why-the-onclick-element-will-trigger-twice-for-label-element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869548/javascript-event-listener-fires-twice-when-clicking-on-text-inside-label-element